# Group with exactly six Sylow 5-subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Give an example of a group with exactly six Sylow 5-subgroups.

I think $A_5$ works because it has 6 subgroups of order 5:

$\langle(12345)\rangle,\langle(12354)\rangle, \langle(12435)\rangle, \langle(12453)\rangle, \langle(12534)\rangle, \langle(12543)\rangle$. Is this right? Is there a simpler group that meets these requirements?

Comment: That is correct $|A_5| = 60 = 5*12$. So the number of $5$-Sylow subgroups  is either $1$ or $6$. You just wrote down 6 $5-$Sylow subgroups.

Comment: i used to think $A_{5}$ was "simple" enough. ;)

Comment: @skmehta "Simple" - Yet another way to see that there is not 1 $5$-Sylow subgroup. Though explicitly listing them is nice.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simpler example, but it's the smallest example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of $A_5$ is a good one. $|A_5| = 60 = 5*12$, so using the Sylow Theorems, $n_5 = 1$ or $n_5 = 6$ (where $n_5$ is the number of $5$-Sylow subgroups). $n_5 \neq 1$ since if $n_5=1$, you would have that the $5$-Sylow subgroup is normal, a contradiction of the simplicity of $A_5$.

Therefore $n_5 = 6$.

In your question statement you explicitly listed the subgroups, which I personally like as a solution since it does not require you to use the fact that $A_5$ is simple.